# PL/SQL Group By - ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle10g

I am writing the following query that I want to display car registration, car group name, model name, cost and the number of bookings for each car.  I have to use an explicit cursor and I have to use an implicit cursor to calculate the number of bookings that belong to each car.

My query is as follows:

```
    SET SERVEROUTPUT ON FORMAT WRAP SIZE 12000
Declare
v_count number;
cursor carcur IS
SELECT * FROM i_car;
v_car carcur%ROWTYPE;
Begin
Select COUNT (registration)
INTO v_count
from i_booking
group by registration;
FOR v_car IN carcur LOOP
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Registration:'|| '  '|| v_car.registration);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Car Group:'|| ' ' ||v_car.car_group_name);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Model Name:'|| ' '||v_car.model_name);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Cost:'|| ' '||v_car.cost);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Total Bookings:'|| ' '||v_count);
DBMS_OUTPUT.NEW_LINE;

END LOOP;
End;
```

The output I am getting is as follows:
Declare
*
ERROR at line 1: 
ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows 
ORA-06512: at line 7

I am sure it has something to do with the return values being put into the variable, but I have no idea how to rectify this.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the trick for me.  I moved my implicit SELECT statement into the cursor for loop and added a WHERE clause saying WHERE registration = v_car.registration;

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON FORMAT WRAP SIZE 12000
    Declare
    v_count number;
    cursor carcur IS
    SELECT * FROM i_car;
    v_car carcur%ROWTYPE;
    Begin
    FOR v_car IN carcur LOOP
    Select COUNT (registration)
    INTO v_count
    from i_booking
    WHERE registration = v_car.registration;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Registration:'|| '  '|| v_car.registration);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Car Group:'|| ' ' ||v_car.car_group_name);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Model Name:'|| ' '||v_car.model_name);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Cost:'|| ' '||v_car.cost);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Total Bookings:'|| ' '||v_count);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.NEW_LINE;
    END LOOP;
    End;
```

Many thanks to everyone for you assistance.

Answer (score 2):

The error you are facing is because you are trying to assign multiple values to a single valued variable.

Your query is returning multiple values primarily because you are using a `group by`. What a `group by` does is, in your case, finds the total count of values in column `registration` for every distinct value in that column.

Suppose, let's see an example-

```
registration | other columns ...
1            | ...
1            | ...
1            | ...
2            | ...
3            | ...
3            | ...
```

Hence the output of your query with the `group by` would be

```
registration | count(registration)
1            | 3
2            | 1
3            | 2
```

Note that the column `registration` is not selected in your `select` list, only `count(registration)` is selected, which according to the example can contain multiple values.

Hence now there are three cases now-

1. If the above is your desired output, clieu's answer above is useful.
2. If you want to get just the count of all the non-null values in the column `registration`, just remove the `group by` clause and you'll be fine.
3. If you want the count of all the `DISTINCT` non-null values in the column `registration`, you can use `count(distinct registration)` and remove `group by` as follows:

   ```
   SET SERVEROUTPUT ON FORMAT WRAP SIZE 12000
   Declare
   v_count number;
   cursor carcur IS
   SELECT * FROM i_car;
   v_car carcur%ROWTYPE;
   Begin
   Select COUNT (DISTINCT registration)
   INTO v_count
   from i_booking;
   FOR v_car IN carcur LOOP
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Registration:'|| '  '|| v_car.registration);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Car Group:'|| ' ' ||v_car.car_group_name);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Model Name:'|| ' '||v_car.model_name);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Cost:'|| ' '||v_car.cost);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Total Bookings:'|| ' '||v_count);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.NEW_LINE;

   END LOOP;
   End;
   /
   ```

Comment: I included my inplicid cursor into the For loop and added a WHERE clause stating WHERE registration = v_car.registration.  That did the trick.  Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs when more than one value is returned from the select count(registration) since you are selecting it into a single variable v_count.

If you are trying to select all of the counts for the various registrations, you'll want to use an array type for v_count, like this:

```
declare
v_count number;
v_counts is table of v_count

Begin
    Select COUNT (registration)
    bulk collect INTO v_counts
    from i_booking
group by registration;

if (v_counts > 0) then
   for i in v_counts.first..last loop
    <do your printing>
   end loop;
end if;
end;
/
```

I also added in an optimization that uses a bulk collect since that will give you slightly faster performance.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I tried to incorporate your edits and got this error:  v_counts is table of v_counts;
         *
ERROR at line 3: 
ORA-06550: line 3, column 10: 
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "IS" when expecting one of the following: 
constant exception <an identifier> 
<a double-quoted delimited-identifier> table LONG_ double ref 
char time timestamp interval date binary national character 
nchar

Comment: Sorry, corrected that defintion of v_count should be  "v_counts is table of v_count"

Answer (score 1):

the error is in the `group by` clause. You are getting multiple rows for `count(registration)` because you have used `group by` on it. The temporary solution for now is to remove the `group by` clause.